# Laravel 5 Dingo API controller

Tags: php, api, rest, laravel, dingo-api

I have been trying to implement a REST API using the Laravel 5 Dingo API package.

This is my routing code:

```
 $api->version('v1', function ($api) {
    $api->get('users/{id}', 'Api\V1\UsersController@show');
});
```

This is my error code:

```
{"message":"Class Api\\V1\\UsersController does not exist","code":-1,"status_code":500}
```

So, where should I place my controller file in order it finds the correct path for my controller ?

I placed the file in `app/http/controllers/Api/V1/` directory but I'm still getting this kind of error.

I am using Dingo API 0.10 for Laravel.

Comment: Does your `UsersController` file have the correct namespace? I.e. does it have `namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1` at the top of the file?

Comment: yes there is `namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1` at the top the Userscontroller

Comment: The only other thing I could recommend with what I can see is to check for spelling mistakes and check you're following the docs properly: https://github.com/dingo/api/wiki/Creating-API-Endpoints 

If you can add more info to your question you may be able to get some more help. Maybe copy paste the output of `route:list`

Comment: Solved this problem my adding full path of the controller in the route `$api->get('users/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\UsersController@show');`

Comment: Glad you got a solution to your problem. You can add your answer if you like!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By adding full path of the controller in the route

`$api->get('users/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\UsersController@show');`

will fix this error.